# Responsively scale an absolutely positioned element

Tags: html, css

I have a circle which needs to have an absolute position as per the attached design. I can achieve the positioning but it doesn't scale responsively with the viewport width. Kindly suggest how can I have a responsive image along with the absolute position. Below is the CSS I applied to the image.

```
.upper-partial-circle
{
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: -10%;
    max-height: 300px;
    top: -1%;
}
```

[image: UI to achieve]

Comment: What is the responsive behavior you are expecting? Scaling?

Comment: Like the circle should be contained in a container(it can be either background image or an image tag) and it should get resized as per the width of the view port.

Comment: It's not possible to answer this question if you don't add the full relevant code

Answer (score 0):

I would try give it a width or height with viewport units. For example height: 10vw; so it's height will be always 10% of the screen's width.

[codepen.io/RoniFlash/pen/wvBxbwM](https://codepen.io/RoniFlash/pen/wvBxbwM)

HTML:

```html
<body>
  <div></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5%;
  left: -5%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: I think this is a good answer but maybe you could add a code example to better illustrate it?

Comment: https://codepen.io/RoniFlash/pen/wvBxbwM 

I hope you thought something similar

Comment: Yep! I was thinking the same thing. Could you edit your answer to include both the CodePen link, and the markup and CSS (so the answer stays relevant even if the link goes dead someday)?

Comment: I would gladly do this but I'm new in this platform and don't know how I can. Only thing I can do now is not deleting the pen.

Comment: There is edit button under your original post, in between "share" and "flag". If you can't find it I can make the edit.

Comment: Can you do it please? then I will see what you meant before.